# Graph matching with constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, matching

I have this problem bellow and I'm not seeing an effective solution but taking the brute force approach. Would anyone mind lending me a hand?

The problem consists of a graph G= (V,E) directed, weighted and acyclic. Edges have weights w(u,v). The value of w(u, v) depends only on the vertex of origin ( w(**u**,x)= w(**u**,y) if (u,x) and (u,y) exist ). Originally, each vertex may have multiple incoming and/ or outgoing edges. The goal is to maintain one outgoing edge per vertex at most in a way the total remaining weight is maximum. Vertices that have outgoing edges **cannot** have incoming ones. For example, consider figure 1. The left-side graph is the original one. Keeping at most one outgoing edge, the right-side graph represents a solution for maximum total weight, 17.

However, there is another constraint to this problem. Each vertex is assigned 2 values, capacity and load. Capacity says how much load it can have attached to. Capacity must be also taken into account while finding the maximum total weight configuration. Figure 2 shows the same graph as figure 1 but now the capacity constraint plays a decisive role. See that the maximum total weight configuration is different in this situation (right-side graph, figure 2).

In summary, there are 3 restrictions in order to get the maximum total weight:

1. Obey capacity limitation;
2. Vertices with outgoing edge don't have incoming ones;
3. Vertices have one outgoing edge at most.

The only solution I've come up is testing all possible configurations, checking if it is a valid and keeping track the maximum. Does anyone have a better approach to tackle this problem?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: You may want to check with [cstheory.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks like [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem to me: pick up a set of edges to maximize profit.

What you can do for sure, is using [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) approach. For example, check [this code](https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-examples/blob/master/knapsack/knapsack.mzn) that solves knapsack problem. Adapting it to your needs should be a rather simple task.

You don't need any matching algorithm with this approach - a solving procedure will build the best possible solution directly. However, it might take a lot of time/memory for larger graphs (thousands edges/nodes).